# Problems installing Ubuntu 16.10 on AMD A10-5750

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, amd-graphics, 16.10

I want to switch from Windows 10 to Ubuntu version 16.10. For this purpose I have installed a new SSD disk dedicated for Ubuntu 16.10.

My Hardware:

- Laptop with AMD A10-5750 CPU
- APU = AMD Radeon HD 8650G
- GPU = AMD Radeon HD 8970M
- BIOS = I can choose boot using "Legacy", "UEFI" and "UEFI with CSM"

Installation problem with Ubuntu 16.10

- Using USB installation
- Get the screen to test or install Ubuntu
- Ubuntu logo pops up, but don't manage to install
- Laptop is then restarted and back to Ubuntu install menu again

Actions done:

- Tried all boot options: Legacy, UEFI and UEFI with CSM
- Tried version 16.04 Ubuntu, same problem
- I have installed SteamOS using Linux Debian on same laptop (another SSD disk). This installation works fine. Running SteamOS on my laptop

Someone who could give me a good advice how I should manage to install Ubuntu 16.10 on my laptop?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Comment: I have looked at your procedure. I manage to come to step 6, then my installation problems are starting!

Comment: Which procedure (answer) on that page did you try? Please [edit] further critical  information such as this into your post as comments can be deleted for a number of reasons. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: Hello Elder Geek. My scenario: I try to install Ubuntu 16.10 using clean and fresh SSD disk. No OS is installed. My Windows 10 SSD is taken out of the laptop. Using installation guide from Ubuntu using USB boot. Does this information help you further Elder Geek? Olav

Comment: When you've done so, drop me a comment and I'll look again.

Comment: Hello Elder Geek. Did you manage to have a look at my comment? Do you have any suggestions how I could come 1 step further in order to install Ubuntu 16.10 on my laptop?

Comment: My apologies for any confusion you may have experienced. I'll try to clarify. Begin by clicking [edit] and adding **the information I requested** to your post. I cannot read your mind, nor see over your shoulder to determine which answer on the page I noted as duplicate you tried (a link might be useful), and no repeating information from your question isn't remotely helpful. [edit]ing requested information into your post is in my experience far more effective.